# Как правильно на Javascript организовать цикл?

Tags: javascript, циклы

Всем привет. Цикл должен выполнится около миллиона раз. При этом нужно уложится в минимальное время. Я знаю например в php определённые циклы (особенно для массивов) работают быстрее других (например foreach). Есть ли что нибудь похожее в Javascript?

**Дополнено.**

Вот цикл, который должен выполнятся миллион раз =) :

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    t = t + '<tr>';
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        t = t + '<td></td>';
    }
    t = t + '</td>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На webo.in есть интересные статьи по поводу ускорения скриптов. В вашем случае подойдет "[Производительность простых и сложных конструкций в JavaScript](http://webo.in/articles/habrahabr/78-javascript-constructions-performance/)".

Comment: Спасибо за статью!

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от того, что является условием выхода из цикла. Сложность выполнения цикла зависит от сложности и частоты проверки условия выхода из него. А это условие зависит от исходной задачи. В некоторых случаях старый добрый

```
for(var i = 0, m = ...; i < m; ++i) {}
```

а в некоторых **do** или **while**.

Comment: Добавил цикл в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

В JavaScript есть аналог foreach

```
for( var item in list )
```

- item - элемент
- list - может быть массивом или обычным объектом

Comment: Этот аналог - не совсем аналог. Нельзя использовать для массивов, так как на разных браузерах работает по разному. Не помню деталей, на на некоторых попадает length вместе с элеменами массива, а на некоторых - нет.

Comment: Абсолютно верно. Причём в вышеуказанной статье проводится тест циклов. Результат показал что цикл for-in явлеятся очень медленным для всех браузеров и в особенности для IE. В общем если вам важен перфоменс и скорость не используйте его.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Я тоже сталкивался. Зато этот цикл очень удобно использовать если вы пользуетесь объектом как ассоциативным массивом.

Answer (score 0):

Я молодой. Может вопроса не понял) Когда-то страдал фигнёй.

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<script>
alert('dddd')
i=1;
while (i<10000000) 
{
alert('ghgj');
i ++
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я здесь говорю о скорости выполнения скрипта. А в вашем случае цикл будет проходить заново только после нажатия "ок" в окне alert..

Comment: Ну да, можно убрать alert) 
Тогда правильный ответ #2) Чуть ниже парень правильно написал)